Problems installing PyAudio
I am currently trying to install PyAudio to use SpeechRecognition in python. I get the error fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
(entire error:
\`Collecting PyAudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.14.tar.gz (47 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
Building wheel for PyAudio (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for PyAudio (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build PyAudio
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for PyAudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[18 lines of output\]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pyaudio
copying src/pyaudio/__init__.py -\> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pyaudio
running build_ext
building 'pyaudio.\_portaudio' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/pyaudio
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -O2 -pipe -g -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O2 -pipe -g -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.11 -c src/pyaudio/device_api.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/pyaudio/device_api.o
src/pyaudio/device_api.c:9:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
9 | #include "portaudio.h"
|          ^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyAudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects\`.

I installed portaudio19-dev, and it didn't do anything. I can find the file under /usr/include/portaudio.h, but, again, it doesn't find it. all dependencies for portaudio are installed as well. I tried both pip install PyAudio and pip install --user PyAudio. Neither work. I am on Linux Mint 21.3 x86_64 and use Pycharm 2024.1.1. Hope someone could help.
I installed portaudio19-dev, and it didn't do anything. I can find the file under /usr/include/portaudio.h, but, again, it doesn't find it. all dependencies for portaudio are installed as well. I tried both pip install PyAudio and pip install --user PyAudio. Neither work. I am on Linux Mint 21.3 x86_64 and use Pycharm 2024.1.1. Hope someone could
Edit: I used the Linux terminal to import PyAudio for python3.11 (which somehow worked). python3.11 -m pip install PyAudio worked. then in pycharm, I could use
source /.venv/bin/activate 
pip install /home/username/.cache/pip/wheel/something/something/something/something/PyAudio-0.2.14-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl

to actually install it. But now when I try to import it, it returns:
ImportError: libportaudio.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'.

EDIT:
I‘ve since switched to arch linux, and can thus no longer use apt (instead I‘ll have to use pacman or yay). I also get a new error in the terminal
[thedisk@archlinux portaudio]$ pypy3 -m pip install pyaudio
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.14.tar.gz (47 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-pypy310
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-pypy310/pyaudio
      copying src/pyaudio/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-pypy310/pyaudio
      running build_ext
      building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio
      gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy3/include/pypy3.10 -c src/pyaudio/device_api.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio/device_api.o
      gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy3/include/pypy3.10 -c src/pyaudio/host_api.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio/host_api.o
      gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy3/include/pypy3.10 -c src/pyaudio/init.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio/init.o
      gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy3/include/pypy3.10 -c src/pyaudio/mac_core_stream_info.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio/mac_core_stream_info.o
      gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy3/include/pypy3.10 -c src/pyaudio/main.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio/main.o
      gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy3/include/pypy3.10 -c src/pyaudio/misc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio/misc.o
      gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy3/include/pypy3.10 -c src/pyaudio/stream.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio/stream.o
      gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy3/include/pypy3.10 -c src/pyaudio/stream_io.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio/stream_io.o
      gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy3/include/pypy3.10 -c src/pyaudio/stream_lifecycle.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-pypy310/src/pyaudio/stream_lifecycle.o
      src/pyaudio/stream_lifecycle.c: In function ‘PyAudio_OpenStream’:
      src/pyaudio/stream_lifecycle.c:249:55: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘thread_id’
        249 |   stream->context.main_thread_id = PyThreadState_Get()->thread_id;
            |                                                       ^~
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pyaudio)

so as far as I understand, gcc is failing (or so I suppose).

when you say you're trying to import it, i'm guessing it is as part of your script which you're editing in PyCharm, correct me if I'm wrong. What is the interpreter version shown in your PyCharm window (as part of your virtual environment)?

@ZohanPolis I am using 3.11 I believe.

Sorry I somehow missed that

I forgot what I did, but now it works. I think it was something with the venv, but I'm absolutely not sure

Edit:
This could be problem with the building of the portaudio API. Download the source code from here: https://files.portaudio.com/download.html and try following the instructions to build PortAudio for Linux: https://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html.
Then you can go ahead and install dependencies and PyAudio in your virtual environment:
source /.venv/bin/activate
sudo apt install python3-pyaudio

You also mentioned you have portaudio19-dev and tried with the wheels previously so I think you have your bases covered. One more dependency you need for PyAudio is python3-all-dev so check if you have that. PyAudio has this problem common among many users when being installed on Linux and/or with Python 3.10 and 3.11. Hope this helps!

I already did that (so now when trying that it just displays “0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 to upgrade“). When freshly installing it (usually via “python3.11 pip install pyaudio“), it provides a path to the wheel of the package. I then go to my IDE and “pip install /path/to/wheel.whl“, and it installs. And then when trying to import pyaudio (or working with packages depending ot that), it displays: “import pyaudio._portaudio as paI
mportError: libportaudio.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory“
